# Print character at place of columns in PDF

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have parsed data from PDF using Tabula, PDFBox and many other tools but the output I am getting is not in the required format. The data is in the form of multi-line tables.

My main aim to print / insert a character every time it encounters a cell boundary.  What will be the best way to do it?

Comment: *"every time it encounters a cell boundary"* - what does that mean? E.g. do all your tables have lines separating the columns? Adding a special char where a text line intersects a vector graphics line is doable. But if there is not always such a line, please indicate how to recognize column borders.

Comment: Column border means where the two lines intersect, intersection of two lines would lead to formation of cell boundary

Comment: What do you mean by *"Column border means where the two lines intersect"*? At the left and right column borders I would expect/require a single line only...